# Jooq - Insert does not update object with generated id

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm inserting using DSL context:

```
val userRecord = create.newRecord(ITR_NE_USER, user)
val x = create.executeInsert(userRecord)
```

I would expect `userRecord` to be updated with the generated ID  (this is Kotlin) - it's still null after the insert.

How do I make it give me the value back?